# How many field homomorphisms are from $\mathbb{Q}[2^{1/3},2^{1/5}]$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

How many field homomorphisms are from $\mathbb{Q}[2^{1/3},2^{1/5}]$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

My idea: Let $\phi:\mathbb{Q}[2^{1/3},2^{1/5}] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a field homomorphism which preserve the order of $2^{1/3}$ and $2^{1/5}$. i.e $\phi(2^{1/3})^3=2$, and $\phi(2^{1/5})^5=2$.

We have three choices for $2^{1/3}$, and five choices for $2^{1/5}$. Thus there are total $15$ possible choices for $\phi:\mathbb{Q}[2^{1/3},2^{1/5}] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: That looks alright, but can you say which these choices are? In particular, what is the degree of your field extension (over the rational numbers), and have you heard of the primitive element theorem?

Comment: Yes. I know what are these choices. and the degree of extension is 15

Comment: Excellent, then you are done.